# Cannot insert document MongoDB database

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am not able to insert data into MongoDB database using `insert` method in Nodejs.

```
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo';
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // db gives access to the database
  const myDb = db.db('learnyoumongo');
  var docs = myDb.collection('docs');
  var obj = {firstName: process.argv[2], lastName: process.argv[3]};
  docs.insert(obj, function(err, res){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('data inserted');
  })
  db.close();
}
```

There is no output coming and connection to the data base is successful but no insertion of data is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem is. Seems like I forgot to add a parenthesis in the end:

```
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo';
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // db gives access to the database
  const myDb = db.db('learnyoumongo');
  var docs = myDb.collection('docs');
  var obj = {firstName: process.argv[2], lastName: process.argv[3]};
  docs.insert(obj, function(err, res){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('data inserted');
  })
  db.close();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this will work for you .

```
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo';
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
mongo.connect(url, function(err, dbobj) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // db gives access to the database
 // const myDb = dbobj.db('learnyoumongo').collection('docs');
 // var docs = myDb.collection('docs');
  var obj = {firstName: process.argv[2], lastName: process.argv[3]};
  dbobj.db('learnyoumongo').collection('docs').insert(obj, function(err, res){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('data inserted');
    dbobj.close();
  })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to insert data into MongoDB using nodejs.

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo";

mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
if (err) throw err;
//access to the database
var myobj = { firstname: "Jhon", lastname: "Mackey" };
db.collection("docs").insertOne(myobj, function(err, res) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log("Data inserted");
db.close();
 });
});
```